# Calling a function from a checkbox issues

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

So I'm really fresh into python and perhaps in over my head. I have created a tkinter checkbox inside the mainloop of my gui that is to call a function outside (aulocale1). When clicking the checkbox I get the **global name aulocale1 is not defined** error. I know this is easily resolved but I've tried googling it and the results don't really make sense. My apologies for the post as I know its something silly.

```
aulocale = IntVar()
aucheck = Checkbutton(self.master, variable=aulocale, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text="AU",command=aulocale1)
aucheck.pack(in_=top, side=LEFT)
```

Function :

```
def aulocale1(self,master):
    self.master.base.replace = "http://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-AU-Site/en_AU"
    self.master.replace = ('','AU')
    self.master.headers = ('REPLACETHISPLIZZZ','en-AU,en;q=0.8')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `aulocale1` is not global function but method in class so you need `self`

```
command=self.aulocale1
```

if this method and checkbox are in the same class

Or

```
command=some_object.aulocale1
```

if method is in different object `some_object`

Comment: Oh woow that's all it was. On goes a further 500 errors to iron out. Really appreciate your quick response!!!. The function I am trying to call does not replace base = "http://www.urlhere.com.au" in my other script. I am getting a NameError: global name 'base' is not defined error. Any idea's how to overcome this?

Comment: what is `base` ? Is this local variable inside some function or class ? Then you can't change it. If it is variable in class then you need `self.base`. If it is variable in function then you may need `global` in function. If it global variable and you do `import script` then it is `script.base`. Everything depends on your code.

Comment: Base is a local variable inside another script. That script is imported into the one I'm making the change from. I assume script.base is what im looking for?